# js spectrum multiple targets

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using a great tool called "[JS Spectrum](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/)." I am using the tool in multiple places and these multiple instances are causing my code to be very long. Obviously, I could just create a class and call the spectrum code on that class. However, I don't see how I can get the event target to tell me which ID called the function so that I can set the change event accordingly.

Comment: I don't see how to pass the full event through to the change event within the spectrum call. In other words, how do I get this: 

$("#colorpicker").spectrum({
    change: function(event) {
     event.target.id
    },

Comment: What about `this`? What's its value in the event handler? BTW, spectrum looks really nice!

Comment: This is why this site is awesome. Because I can rack my brain for days as to why I can't get something to work only to realize that the problem is that I am an idiot. Of course I can just pass $(this) through. Thanks bfavaretto.

Comment: You don't even need to pass it, just use `this` inside your function that handles the event - http://jsfiddle.net/e4FuH/

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` inside the event handler will point to the field where the color was changed:

```html
<input type='text' id="custom1" class="picker" />
<input type='text' id="custom2" class="picker" />
```

```javascript
function colorChanged(newColor) {
    console.log('color at ' + this.id + ' changed to ' + newColor)   
}

$(".picker").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change : colorChanged
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e4FuH/1/